# Windows Batch - How can I modify a file and keep only the substring starting with "<?xml" and ending with "</testsuites>"?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file with the following structure:

```
unwantedtext
<?xml ... />
<testsuites ...>
...
</testsuites>
<testsuites ...>
...
</testsuites>
unwantedtext
```

I want to write a .bat script to remove the unwanted text from the file.

I tried googling the question and found answers to some similar problems, but I didn't understand the code well enough to be able to modify it and make it do what I need it to.

I found some interesting code here: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429

```
set "tail=%str:*x=%"
set "head=%str:x=" & rem."%"
```

Here's the faulty code that I managed to write:

```
SET str="notwanted<?xml><testsuites></testsuites><testsuites></testsuites>notwanted"
set tail="%str:*<?xml>=%
echo %tail%
:: "<testsuites></testsuites><testsuites></testsuites>notwanted"
set "head=%str:testsuites=" & rem."%"
:: < was unexpected at this time.
```

I expected the last command to at least remove the first "testsuites" it found, but it doesn't even run successfully.

Comment: This looks like a SoapUI project, and SoapUI uses Groovy for programming purposes, which is a kind of Java-like scripting language. Can't you use Groovy for this?

Comment: are the number of `<testsuites></testsuites>` sections the same per `<?xml>` block? and are their multiple blocks per file?

Comment: There is only one <?xml> tag and there is a variable number of testsuites tags after it.

Comment: added a section to my answer based on your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through all of your lines like this:

```
@echo off

set "one=unwantedtext"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims= tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\Your\Text\File.txt") do (
    set "line=%%A"
    echo(!line:%one%=!
)

pause
```

`for /f` loops through the contents of your file; delayed expansion is required here since the value of your line variable will change each iteration of the loop, and we need to process it each time. With delayed expansion you use exclamation points instead of percent signs, so separating a variable substring looks like `!line:%one%=!` where `!line!` represents your parameter (`%%A` in the example) and `%one%` is the first unwanted word we set prior to looping.

This will be your basic premise - for the testsuites where more information is contained within your angle brackets you'll probably want to have a nested loop for those and change your delimiter to `>`. I'll keep adding to this answer as I have time to show how to handle the other lines specifically if you're having more trouble.

---

**EDIT BASED ON CLARIFICATION**
I got committed to this - it's likely much easier to do via powershell, but I broke it up into small little chunks that I've separated with `REM \\\\\\...` to make them easier to digest:

```
@echo off

set "new=C:\Fresh\Text\File.txt"
set "txt=C:\Current\Text\File.txt"
set "xml=^<?xml"
set "tst=^</testsuites^>"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%A in (%txt%) do (
    set "bgn=%%A"
    if not !bgn!==%xml%!bgn:%xml%=! (set /a count += 1
    ) ELSE (goto block)
)
REM \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
:block
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%B in ('findstr /n "^" "%txt%"') do (
    set "end=%%B"
    if !end:~-13!==%tst% set "last=!end:~0,-14!"
)
REM \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%C in (%txt%) do (
    set /a line += 1
    if not !line! LEQ !count! (if not !line! GTR !last! (echo %%C))
)>>%new%

pause
```

You don't have to have so many variables, but I prefer them to help keep things organized and they make it easier to tweak code blocks.

1. In the first section we set all of our constant variables, enable delayed expansion, and use our first `for` loop to count how many lines into our text file our `<?xml>` tag is; it does so by looping through the text file and checking to see if each line contains the `xml` variable - if it doesn't, it adds one to the counter - if it does, it moves onto the next section `:block`
2. The `for` loop in `:block` finds our `tst` variable, but instead of counting it uses `findstr` to number the lines, then it just removes the number part by saying `!end:~-13!`, where 13 is the number of characters that `</testsuites>` contains (this will need to be modified if you have a different tag. The line number is then saved in a variable using `!end:~0,-14!` (`:</testsuites>` with the colon).
3. The last block loops through all the lines in our text file, and uses `if` statements to grab the lines between the numbers we retrieved from the first two loops and echo them into a new text file.

Hopefully this was what you were looking for; remember to escape your angle brackets!

Reference: [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), [variable substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that the text that needs to be removed is multiline and can change in the future, so I'd like to search for the first <?xml> and last </testsuites> tags and delete anything that is not in between those.
I needed some batch code to run with Jenkins, but I think I'll just write something in c++ and make Jenkins run that as it would probably be much simpler.

Comment: ahhh I understand your question now; i'll add that to my answer when I have time

Answer (score 1):

If the unwanted text is in separate lines you could use [`findstr /N`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to get the line numbers of `<?xml ... />` and the last occurrence of `</testsuites>`, then use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to return only lines in that range, like this, for instance:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"

rem // Initialise variables:
set "NUMA=" & set "NUMB="
rem // Get line numbers of (first) `<?xml .*/>` and last `</testsuites>`:
for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /R /C:"^<?xml .*/>" /C:"</testsuites>$" "%_FILE%"') do (
    rem /* Variable `NUMA` becomes written in the first iteration only while `NUMB` becomes
    rem    overwritten every time, so `NUMA` reflects the first occurence and `NUMB` the last: */
    set "NUMB=%%N" & if not defined NUMA set "NUMA=%%N"
)
rem // Determine how many lines to skip:
set /A "NUMA-=1"
if %NUMA% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%NUMA%") else (set "SKIP=")

rem // Skip as many lines at the beginning as indicated by `NUMA`:
for /F "%SKIP% delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
    rem // Store current line string, extract leading line number:
    set "LINE=%%L" & set /A "NUML=LINE"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Leave loop as soon as current line number exceeds `NUMB`:
    if !NUML! gtr %NUMB% endlocal & goto :END
    rem // Return current line string with preceding line number removed:
    echo(!LINE:*:=!
    endlocal
)
:END

endlocal
exit /B
```

Given the batch file is called `clean-xml.bat` and the input file is named `file.xml`, use the following command line:

```cmd
clean-xml.bat "D:\path\to\your\file.xml"
```

To write the output to another file, say `file_NEW.xml`, use this:

```cmd
clean-xml.bat "D:\path\to\your\file.xml" > "D:\path\to\your\file_NEW.xml"
```

---

If the unwanted text may occur in the same lines as the portions `<?xml ... />` and/or `</testsuites>`, the script becomes a bit more complicated:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"
(set ^"_LF=^
%= empty line =%
^")
rem // Initialise variables:
set "NUMA=" & set "NUMB="
rem // Get line numbers of (first) `<?xml .*/>` and last `</testsuites>`:
for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /R /C:"<?xml .*/>" /C:"</testsuites>" "%_FILE%"') do (
    rem /* Variable `NUMA` becomes written in the first iteration only while `NUMB` becomes
    rem    overwritten every time, so `NUMA` reflects the first occurence and `NUMB` the last: */
    set "NUMB=%%N" & if not defined NUMA set "NUMA=%%N"
)
rem // Determine how many lines to skip:
set /A "NUMA-=1"
if %NUMA% gtr 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%NUMA%") else (set "SKIP=")

rem // Skip as many lines at the beginning as indicated by `NUMA`:
for /F "%SKIP% delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
    rem // Store current line string, extract leading line number:
    set "LINE=%%L" & set /A "NUML=LINE"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Remove preceding line number from line string:
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    rem // The following block is only executed for the first line:
    if defined NUMA (
        rem // Remove everything in front of (first) `<?xml .*/>` portion:
        set "LINE=!LINE:*<?xml =<?xml !" & set "NUMA="
    )
    rem // Check current line number:
    if !NUML! gtr %NUMB% (
        rem // Leave loop as soon as current line number exceeds `NUMB`:
        endlocal & goto :END
    ) else if !NUML! equ %NUMB% (
        rem // This section is only executed for the last line:
        set "COLL=" & set "ITEM="
        rem /* Replace `</testsuites>` instances by line-breaks temporarily,
        rem    iterate through single-line items, rebuild them bus skip last one;
        rem    this is done as a line might contain more than one `</testsuites>`
        rem    instance, but only the text behind the last one is to be removed: */
        for /F "delims=" %%K in (^"#!LINE:^</testsuites^>^=#^%_LF%%_LF%#!#^") do (
            for /F "delims=" %%E in (""!COLL!!ITEM:~1^,-1!^</testsuites^>"") do (
                if defined ITEM (endlocal & set "COLL=%%~E") else endlocal
            )
            set "ITEM=%%K"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        set "LINE=!COLL!"
    )
    rem // Return current line string:
    echo(!LINE!
    endlocal
)
:END

endlocal
exit /B
```

This batch file is to be called in the same way as the above one.